# Validação de Datas usando JDateChooser

Tags: java, swing, jdatechooser

Estou tentando validar duas datas no seguinte caso:

Criei uma JFrame que recebe dois campos de data usando o JdateChooser, como mostro abaixo:

Primeiro campo o usuário informa a data de desligamento, segundo campo o usuário informa a data de pagamento.

Agora entra a validação, após colocar o segundo campo, tenho que fazer uma validação entre eles, que a data de pagamento não pode ser maior que 10 dias da data de desligamento.

Estava tentando colocar esta validação na hora que o usuário escolher a data de pagamento.

Estou tentando fazer esta validação porem não estou conseguindo, já tentei comprar usando o seguinte código abaixo:

```html
if (txtDataDes.getDate().before(txtDataPg.getDate())) {
```

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Pro coincidência, eu já tive uma duvida parecida e a resposta pode te servir também. Se quiser algo mais específico, edite a pergunta e forneça um **[mcve]** para que seja possível analisar melhor seu problema.

Comment: Na realidade não entendi muito bem, mas já estou a horas programando e não estou raciocinando direito, vou verificar seu post amanhã, assim que encontrar uma solução coloco a resposta aqui. att.